# How is a blockchain hosted

Tags: blockchain, hosting, cryptocurrency

I have a question about crypto (I'm new to crypto and blockchain)
How is it actually hosted? like if a create a blockchain like fireship's video (https://youtu.be/qF7dkrce-mQ) how will I actually host it?

Answer (score 0):

Full Nodes host the complete Blockchain:
"A full node does everything that a regular node does, but it also contains an entire copy of the blockchain ledger" ( source: https://www.gemini.com/cryptopedia/masternode-dash-bitcoin-node )

Comment: O, but how does one node connects to another, also are there any crypto built with node.js which I can look into?

Comment: I mean how do they change and verify

Comment: Also, every tutorial I look there is "far from complete", is there any complete tutorial for creating a crypto?

Comment: most Blockchains are Build as a Peer-to-Peer (P2P) Network, so you need a Peer-Discovery. ( https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/p2p_network.html )